# Meteor - Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

When I run command to run project got this error. Same project has no problems in other computers and even other projects also working perfectly in my computer. (this is the problem in a specific project) Here is the error:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
C:\Users\Prem\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Prem\AppData\Local\Temp\mt-u3v850.kc33q\os\classcraft:googleapis.js'
```

Comment: Try running it after a ```meteor reset``` ? But be aware that whatever is in metor's mongodb will be lost.

Comment: Tried this too. But not solved.

Comment: It's failing on a missing file: `classcraft:googleapis.js` - is that because you didn't do a `meteor npm install` first? Note that using `meteor npm install` ensures that you get the right version of node to match meteor's version